# Algorithms - are double ended selection sorts really faster than single ended ones?

Tags: algorithm

A double ended selection sort, one that swaps both min and max, is claimed to be faster to be an ordinary selection sort, even thought the number of comparisons is the same. I understand that it gets rid of some of the looping, but if the number of comparisons stay the same, how are they faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `faster` depends on *machine*. `[though] the number of comparisons is the same` doesn't hold: comparing pairs of (input) values, only the non-larger is a candidate for minimum, the non-smaller one for maximum.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean? It's very unlikely that the two algorithms perform exactly the same number of comparisons in all cases. It's hard to answer the question as-is, because essentially you're asking to either prove or refute some third party claims that you're not actually describing. It's also somewhat of a guess what a "double ended selection sort" is -- do you have a link to the implementation you're discussing?

Comment: I show in my answer, both with a practical demonstration and mathematical analysis, that double-ended selection sort performs more comparisons than regular selection sort. So the assumption of this question that they perform the same number of comparisons is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's implementations of selection sort and double ended selection sort that count comparisons performed.

If you run it, you'll see that double-ended selection sort always performs *more* comparisons than regular selection sort.

```
import random

def selsort(xs):
    N = len(xs)
    comparisons = 0
    for i in xrange(N):
        m = i
        for j in xrange(i+1, N):
            comparisons += 1
            if xs[j] < xs[m]: m = j
        xs[i], xs[m] = xs[m], xs[i]
    return comparisons

def deselsort(xs):
    N = len(xs)
    comparisons = 0
    for i in xrange(N//2):
        M = m = i
        for j in xrange(i+1, N-i):
            comparisons += 2
            if xs[j] < xs[m]: m = j
            if xs[j] >= xs[M]: M = j
        xs[i], xs[m] = xs[m], xs[i]
        if M == i: M = m
        xs[N-i-1], xs[M] = xs[M], xs[N-i-1]
    return comparisons


for rr in xrange(1, 30):
    xs = range(rr)
    random.shuffle(xs)
    xs0 = xs[:]
    xs1 = xs[:]
    print len(xs), selsort(xs0), deselsort(xs1)
    assert xs0 == sorted(xs0), xs0
    assert xs1 == sorted(xs1), xs1
```

That's because the number of comparisons for regular selection sort is:

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n(n-1)/2
```

For double-ended selection sort, the number of comparisons is (for odd n -- the even case is similar)

```
2(n-1) + 2(n-3) + 2(n-5) + ... + 2
= (n-1)+(n-2)+1 + (n-3)+(n-4)+1 + ... 2+1+1
= ((n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1) + (n-1)/2
= n(n-1)/2 + (n-1)/2
```

(Here, I'm rewriting each term `2(n-i)` as `(n-i) + (n-i-1) + 1`)

Comment: Does this mean doubled ended selection sorts are slower?

Comment: In the inner cycle you only need the second comparison if the result of the first one is false. You will save some comparison this way.

Comment: Ok not exactly the same amount but the limit if we divide the number of comparisons by each other is going to be 1. So it is like asymptotically the same or not?